# Sublime Text doesn't run with `sudo` without `-E`

Tags: sudo, sublime-text

I guess I made some damage to my settings because now I'm unable to run Sublime Text as root without `-E`:

```
subl //works
sudo subl //doesn't work (no errors, just silence)
sudo -E subl //works.
```

How can I fix this?

---

Output of `env`:

```
XDG_VTNR=7
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/daria
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
COMP_WORDBREAKS=    
"'><;|&(:
SESSION=ubuntu
TERM=xterm-256color
VTE_VERSION=4002
SHELL=/bin/bash
WINDOWID=69206026
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1341
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=
GTK_MODULES=unity-gtk-module
LC_ALL=
USER=daria
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
PWD=/home/daria
JOB=unity-settings-daemon
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
PAPERSIZE=a4
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/daria
XDG_SEAT=seat0
LANGUAGE=en
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
LOGNAME=daria
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-B8OeFaNcXl
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
INSTANCE=
UPSTART_JOB=unity7
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
XAUTHORITY=/home/daria/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Output of `sudo env`:

```
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
TERM=xterm-256color
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
USERNAME=root
HOME=/root
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
SUDO_USER=daria
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
```

Content of `/etc/sudoers`:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults    env_keep="https_proxy"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

daria ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

Comment: You shouldn't open Sublime Text using either of the two methods (you should use `sudo -H subl`, `gksudo subl`, or `pkexec subl`) but other than that the problem seems to be in the environment, please post the output of `env` and `sudo env`.

Comment: I notice you don't have `DISPLAY` set in `sudo`'s environment. Can you open Sublime Text (or any other graphical application for that matter) with this command? `sudo -H DISPLAY=:0 subl`

Comment: tried, nope - same silence. Maybe I should add `DISPLAY` variable to sudo's env?

Comment: Your `sudo env` output is also much different from mine. Another thing, why is `HOME` set to `/root` in `sudo env`'s output? It should be `/home/daria` unless you're ran `sudo -H env` or ran `sudo env` while logged in as root already. Do you remember having done something in particular before the problem showed up? Changes to configuration files etc? Well no, adding `DISPLAY` to `sudo`'s environment won't change much if `sudo -H DISPLAY=:0 subl` didn't work. I mean it probably should be added at some point, but the problem seems extended to the envrinoment in general.

Comment: I guess you're right, and I remember I changed some settings while trying to make work some another thing  but now it's impossible to revert it - it was made few month ago(( Can you suggest something I can restore this?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you did it's hard :) however `sudo`'s behavior is ruled by `sudo`'s and PAM's configuration. Did you change `/etc/sudoers` or some file related to PAM's configuration (something in `/etc/pam.d`)?

Comment: Yep, /etc/sudoers - it's 100%, but as I see the only thing I changed is adding `daria ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: It doesn't seem likely for that to affect the environment, however just to be sure you could try to restore the default `/etc/sudoers`. I pasted a [clean `/etc/sudoers` here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14566538/), see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know what was the problem :) I'll write an answer, but do you still have the old configuration file by any chance? If you do could you quickly post it to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com)? (you can do that easily from the command line like so: `</path/to/old/etc/sudoers pastebinit -a Daria`)

Comment: Done [old sudoers](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14566642/)

Comment: Found it! The problem is this: `Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"`, I added it to my `/etc/sudoers` and I now get the same output as yours for `sudo env`. Just restore your old `/etc/sudoers` and remove that line and it should be fine. Quickly reading what that thing does exactly and posting an answer.

Comment: Looks stupid... How can It make such damage?((

Comment: I have no clue. I tried Googling the line and couldn't really understand what that would be for, so I guess I'll have to dig `man sudo`. However I posted the answer in the meantime.

Comment: I investigated further, check the updated answer. You may actually want to keep `https_proxy` if you wish to use a proxy e.g. with `apt-get`, so if you configured one and that's the case you probably want replace the line with `Defaults env_keep+="https_proxy"` instead of removing it altoghether. However more precisely the problem was that `Defaults env_keep="foo"` *unset* tons of other variables in the previous environment, in particular `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`, which made running GUI applications impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the environment set by the `sudo` command.

The non-functional environment is set because of this line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"
```

Which affects the environment in different ways, such as:

- `DISPLAY` and`XAUTHORITY` not set (which cause the problem)
- `HOME` set to `/home/root`

And probably in other ways as well.

If you wish to keep `https_proxy` from the previous environment when running `sudo` (this is often useful in order to be able to use a proxy when running `apt-get`), change the line to this one:

```
Defaults env_keep+="https_proxy"
```

So that the other needed environment variables won't be unset.

Otherwise if you don't have a reason to keep `https_proxy` from the previous environment when running `sudo`, you can just remove the whole line altoghether.